# What were Norma and Gloria doing in the season 2 finale?

Tags: plot-explanation, orange-is-the-new-black

In the season 2 finale of Orange is the New Black...

> Norma (the nearly mute) attempts to create a poison from apple seeds to give to Vee (the ringleader of the black gang) after Vee attacks Red (the Russian ex-chef). Gloria (the Latino chef), tells her that it isn't possible to make enough poison from that many apples, and together they conspire to do... something. This involves dog hair, eggs, and something that is ground up. After creating this thing, Norma blows something onto the back of (or into the hair of) Vee.

My question is - what were they making? What was their plan? And did it succeed?

Did the concoction leave Vee with impaired judgement, leading her to alienate her followers? Or did the plan simply not work, as other events unfolded? What was the purpose of the dog hair?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### They were making a "curse"

In Gloria Mendoza's flashback we see that she used to have a side business selling charms to bring good luck. That would also mean that she believed in making curses as well. Her solution to the Vee problem was to curse her.

We see later that misfortune does befall Vee, but whether it was because of Mendoza's spell or not is up to the viewer.

Comment: Upvoted, but is this idea supported by anything other than Gloria's belief in the supernatural? There has been no evidence of Norma beling liable to believe in this sort of thing.

Comment: @DrRDizzle - Another clue I suppose is the ingredients. I remember seeing eggs and dog hair. The way the concoction was delivered (blown in Vee's direction) is another clue. And I guess if Norma was desperate enough to try making cyanide from apple seeds then she'd be willing to try the supernatural.